# What does the column after destination in iptables overview show?

Tags: linux, iptables

If I print the `iptables` overview with `iptables -L` I get the following output:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  -- !richtercloud.de      anywhere             tcp dpt:http to:192.168.178.30:3128
```

where either the last column is a seperate column without a header (What does it show? Why is there no header?) or the continuation of the destination column (denoting restrictions of the "anywhere" condition).

I might have created the rule with `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 ! -s 192.168.178.30 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.178.30:3128` (don't rely to it and it shouldn't be important to be able to answer the question) - I'm just gettting started with `iptables` (and have to face such - let's be gentle and call it - nonsense already).

I'm running `iptables` v1.4.21 on Ubuntu 15.04 with Linux 4.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why there is no heading is someting for the devs to answer, it is probably because is "sort of" part of the destination, or it can mean different things depending on context - so more of a general purpose field.

The source and destination columns are used to match the packet IP addresses, and the `tcp dpt:http` matches the destination port.

Then as this is a NAT rule, the next part describes what we want to happen to the packet if it matches.   In this case, we want to modify the destination IP and port of the packet so it goes to the proxy server.

Effectively this is a transparent proxy rule - it will grap any packets that are not originating from richtercloud.de, destined for anywhere on port 80, and send them over the the proxy server.